# CSS applying opacity from child to parent layer

Tags: css, opacity, erase

Is there a way in CSS how the child layer to apply opacity to its parent, so the affected area of the parent element inherits the oppacity set i.e. the child element to make "opacity hole" so the body background (or the root parent's element background) appear in the specified area?

[image]

Comment: give us some of your code you tried and eventually a screen of result expected ...  beside is it something of like this you try to do ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/nKAka/  or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GHqtd ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking BUT a child **always** inherits the opacity of it's parent.

Comment: I mean, making something like a "window" through all the underlying layers so the main background (background of the body or another styled element) becomes visible in that particular area. By setting opacity or another property on a layer that appears in very front.

Comment: Not really possible but if you have a design you could show there may be options around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a border hack, so the div is all border and the non-bordered part is empty. If you want to have content in the div, make another div that goes on top of the border div.

http://jsfiddle.net/1o1sp7o3/1/

```
#box {
border-top:50px solid black;
border-left:40px solid black;
border-right:50px solid black;
border-bottom:60px solid black;
width:200px;
height:200px;
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:2px solid red;
top:0;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: that's a guess, in'it ? :)

Comment: @GCyrillus huh? Not a guess, a solution. I have created a box... with a hole in it.

Comment: So were my links in my comment , trying to get some reaction from the OP ... your guess goes for a square in middle  :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP wants; it's not what my 'guess' is they want. But just for future reference; it's better not to hazard such guesses, but wait until you get clarification.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear what OP wanted. A div with a hole in it so you can see through it.

Comment: Almost but not exactly. I want a part of an element to become opaque and only this part to be like that (not applying the opacity to the whole parent element, preserving all other parts of that element visible). The child element is supposed to be something like the clipping mask in photoshop (applying opacity not to itself but to the area of the parent element that lies under). So for example, when I set the background-attachetment to the body element to "fixed" and scroll the page this place to show the main background part over which it currently is.

Comment: @user3343023 Why won't what I've done work in the same way? Also, what you want to do isn't exactly possible with CSS at this point. You could use a PNG with transparency?

Comment: Yes, I can do it with PNG with transparency "holes" placed here and there, but it would cause making huge (or multiple) PNGs for long pages and multiple backgrounds for each page if I want to place the opacity elswhere according to the page's surface... And that makes it less dynamic, that's why I asked if there's a method to accomplish it I am not familiar with.

Comment: And about why I think it is not exactly the expected solution - that is bacause the bordered box which is used, could not include contents on its border (where the content of the erased layer would be) and it can only add its contents on the empty place (which is supposed to be erased). For applying content on the black border I'd have to use another element which overlays it but this layer would have contents on the "erased" area as well. Of course, I can set top, left, right and bottom divs around the empty area but putting synchronized content on various divs dynamically is headache.

Comment: @user3343023 That's why I called it a "hack". You can definitely make it work for your purposes, but it's not exactly pretty. But as far as I know its the easiest way to deal with this purely with CSS.